# Bone weighting failed

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have had my bone weighting fail before however all the solutions I have do not work for this mesh I have removed doubles separated loose parts and recalculated the faces.

I don't understand why it cannot be weighted it is a regular Female character

I have the model here
([image]

Can someone help me understand what the problem is so that I can deal with this if it happens again.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=Bone+heat+weight&tab=votes

Comment: that question did not get a good answer  i have also provided a blend file so that it is easier for anyone who tries to answer to figure out my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies on the eyes socket.

I could automatically weight the mesh[image] with this procedure: i selected all eyes socket (the vertices not selected in the picture), pressed P for separate vertices into a new object, then automatically weighted the body. After doing this you can rejoin the two meshes, remove doubles, select the eyes socket and manually weight them.

Make sure you are working in the "basis" shape key!